# CakePHP 1.3 URLs not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I'm having a problem with CakePHP 1.3 while transferring it from Nginx to Apache, as I said in the title the URLs don't work apart from the home page.

Also, I've made some changes to CakePHP so the directory structure is slightly different. It looks like this:

- files

  - app
  - lib
  - plugins
  - vendor
- webroot

This is my .htaccess file which resides inside 'webroot':

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a lot of rep for a "doesn't work" question. Assuming you pointed apache at the webroot dir you are [missing AllowOverride All](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html) probably - though you _shouldn't_ be using htaccess files if you have access to modify the conf files anyway.

Comment: That's what I thought but I actually needed to enable mod rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod rewrite from the command line, like this:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```